# How does one get Google mobile in Chrome?

Tags: http, google-chrome, mobile

I'm trying to view Google's mobile search site on my desktop version of Chrome.

I've tried changing the user agent to my iPhone's user agent via `chrome.exe --user-agent="...."`, but that was unsuccessful. Are there factors besides the user agent which determine what version of Google's site is retrieved?

How can I get the mobile version of Google.com to be retrieved?

Comment: I would start the AVD manager and fire up a device :)

Comment: I would, but I'm specifically looking to get the response in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating to http://google.com/m will bring you directly to the mobile version of google.com

Whereas:
`http://m.google.com` would be a listing of many products.

The m.google.com link contains most of the most used Google Products, so search would look like this:
http://www.google.com/m?source=mobileproducts&dc=gorganic

Comment: yes i did, and it brings me to the mobile version. what happens for you, @TomislavMarkovski ? Why do you ask?

Comment: I think you typed "m.google.com" when you meant "google.com/m"

Comment: Oh, I see. They used to be the same. google.com/m does go directly to search now, I see. Live and Learn...I updated the answer to show the difference and more direct link. Thanks @xixonia

Comment: No problem, as a side note...some user-agent info for Chrome: http://techdows.com/2011/12/google-chrome-now-has-built-in-user-agent-switcher.html Chrome supports user-agent switching on-the-fly using the Dev Tools.